# Process without name

Tags: linux, process, malware

I have a web server, due to an outdated Wordpress some hacker uploaded a webshell. Throught it, he launched a process but the ps command is not showing any name for the process:

```
root@serv ~ # ps aux|grep  " 326 "
us432   326  0.0  0.0  25032  4476 ?        S    Aug27   0:16       
root     3334  0.0  0.0  16656  2092 pts/2    S+   14:58   0:00 grep  326
```

Due to that fact I couldn't discover the problem until today.

The server OS is Debian 8, with Apache and PHP 7. The website is running under a non-privileged user.

I've search how to launch a process without name or how can I delete it's name during the execution but I didn't find anything.

Does anyone know how is this possible?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167490/how-can-a-process-appear-to-have-different-name-in-ps-output

Comment: while the duplicate link above wont directly help you it might help you prevent the issue the next time.

additionally for your question itself this might help you understand how a process is named in linux, where you get the info from px aux etc, so you can check yourself what the process is.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16165667/change-process-name-without-changing-argv0-in-linux

Comment: Thanks for your responses, now I see how I can launch this kind of processes and therefore think in something to detect them. Regards.

Answer (score 2):

First, a suggestion: since you know the PID, use `ps -p` to list a specific PID. My standard, goto command is `ps -fp <pid>`.

I'm guessing the executable's name is made up of unprintable characters, just to make it hard to find or manipulate. (All characters are valid in file names on *nix; some of them are just hard to properly escape.) To display those hidden characters, try `ps -fp 326 | cat -vet`. I use the pneumonic device "take my cat to the vet" to remember those flags which display all unprintable characters. The same trick can be used with, for example, `ls` output to discover that the name of the file you can't delete ends with a tab character.

Comment: I didn't think about using those parameters of cat to check if the executable's name had unprintable characters. I will have it in account if the problem returns, thanks!